# new_version package can't fetch the store version Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

My app using the latest version of 'new_version' package. It was working properly, but out of no reason it throws a RangeError. It can't fetch the storeVersion value. My app is live in google play store, no issue.

[Range error that 'new_version package' throws (mentioned above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WElk2.png)

The below image is where the error thrown from new_version package
[The source of range error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MVAE.jpg)

It was working then, but now working now. And my live app is broken now. It is unusual because i haven't even updated a new version in 2 weeks.

Could it be happening because of the google's "Ongoing issue with statistics reporting between 2022-06-11 and 2022-07-19" issue? I'm not sure if everyone sees it but here is the screenshot below;
[google's issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDfEL.png)

I have sent the new version to review immediately but I'm looking for other solutions for fixing it 'now'. I've already lost 200+ users since this last 7 hours. And I don't want to wait google's review process for days and my app to stay closed. In this situation, I may not have much to do but I need to ask. Should I contact with google? Or maybe another small task that i can't see at the moment. If you can see a way, please tell me what can I do. I will be appreciated galaxy-size. I'm also leaving the flutter doctor results below. Thank you in advance.

[flutter doctor results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWIqn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the method used in the **new_version** package is **web scrapping**. If the web playstore changes, the **new_version** package may crash and need adjustment

Hope this useful..

you can try adding **current_version** data in your **database** instead of **new_version** package or **waiting** for new update from **new_version** package